# Can apex charts line graphs ignore zero or empty values?

Tags: apexcharts

i am using apex charts for a line chart pulling through from form submissions. I have 30 values in the data series and 30 items in the x axis categories which correspond to the created_at dates for each data value. Works fine when there is data for date but when as often happens there is no submission for a date the graph line shoots to zero and the graph looks crap. Any suggestions on how to ignore zero values? Thanks.

Comment: Replace 0 with `null` for efect [like this](https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/line-charts/missing-null-values/)