# Apex charts - ignoring null values in a data stream

Tags: apexcharts

I am using a line chart in Apex Charts within Home Assistant to display the data stream from a solar inverter.  The data points are null at night of course resulting in.

[image: an odd looking chart]

This is similar but not the same as [Can apex charts line graphs ignore zero or empty values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165749/can-apex-charts-line-graphs-ignore-zero-or-empty-values).

Ideally the nulls would be replaced by a straight line from the last non-zero datapoint to the first point next day.
But from https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/line-charts/missing-null-values/ I cannot see how to apply this to a stream.  It's like it needs an "if" somehow.
I have tried using

```
series:
    fill_raw: last
```

and

```
apex_config:
    curve: smooth
```

without success.

Any clues on how this would be done?
TIA

Comment: please share the code you attempted if possible a working example!

Comment: Ok. Posted here https://pastebin.com/tGz3y7DY

The relevant data is "Total Solar Energy" dataset.

Comment: Here are a couple of other views. It's a bit hard to get raw data.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_JlMdKo6NVyE1CcGwx7kmL_LZFCZguY/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18eglOIXlymuoxYe-mbB0S78DFNDCDI5j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Since all charts appear to have only one line, you could completely filter out (including the x values) those data points that have `null` or zero as their `y` value. That will result in the chart showing a segment over the night zone, uniting the last non-zero of the afternoon with the fist non-zero of the morning. But unless you share your code, we cannot give but superficial hints like these ...

Comment: "unless you share your code" - is the link not working? https://pastebin.com/tGz3y7DY

Comment: Bump. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. Just add one more configuration to your entity:

```yaml
    group_by:
      func: last
```

Here's a complete updated entity, from your pastebin:

```yaml
series:
  - entity: sensor.total_solar_energy
    color: green
    fill_raw: last
    group_by:
      func: last
```

FWIW, thanks for posting this! I had the `group_by` part, and you had the `fill_raw` part. Putting them together got mine to work.

Comment: Thanks! My charts now look smooth  - and cool. Glad you got something from it also.